# Create Postgres with knex.js trigger to update time after updating the table

Tags: postgresql, triggers, knex.js

I have a table with id, username, job, job_id, created_at, and updated_at columns. I used knex.js to create the table and I want the table to capture the time if there are any modifications on the table, for example, if the column job is updated from the frontend, the column updated_at should store the time at which the column was updated.

I am new to Postgres triggers, but I tried to implement this;

```
const FUNCTION_NAME = 'on_time_update';

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ${FUNCTION_NAME}()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN
    NEW.updated_at = now();
    RETURN NEW
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

export async function up(knex: Knex): Promise<void> {
await knex.raw(createOnUpdateTrigger('jobs', FUNCTION_NAME));
}

export async function drop(knex: Knex): Promise<void> {
await knex.raw(dropTrigger('jobs', FUNCTION_NAME));
}
```

using knex, I created a trigger;

```
createOnUpdateTrigger: (name, table, procedure) => `
     CREATE TRIGGER ${name}
     BEFORE UPDATE on ${table}
     FOR EACH ROW
     EXECUTE PROCEDURE ${procedure}();
`
dropTrigger: (name, table) => `
     DROP TRIGGER ${name} ON ${table};
`
```

by doing this, I am able to successfully create the migration, but my column is not being updated and I am not getting errors. I am not sure what am I doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated as I am new to this! Thanks!

Comment: I do not know  knex.js, but it seems that as soon as you create the trigger, you drop it. So it does not exist when you execute an update.

Comment: Thanks, I will check that, but, is my trigger function right? I am trying to capture the current time using now(); when the table is updated. I feel like I am doing something wrong there.

Comment: From a Postgres perspective your trigger function is absolutely correct.